# use pivot table with number of different rows and columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, nested-lists

Hi I have a json file with several columns of questions some are the same others change as in the following json file

```
apend = [
    {
        "first_name": "Raúl Pedro",
        "last_name": "Moreno Zavaleta",
        "email": "raulmoreno147@gmail.com",
        "custom_questions": [
            {
                "title": "a",
                "value": "si"
            },
            {
                "title": "b",
                "value": "no"
            },
            {
                "title": "c",
                "value": "001"
            } 
        ],
        "status": "approved",
        "create_time": "2023-02-18T17:25:30Z"
    },
    {
        
        "first_name": "Milagritos",
        "last_name": "Canales Lora",
        "email": "milacanaleslora@gmail.com",
        "custom_questions": [
            {
                "title": "a",
                "value": "no"
            },
            {
                "title": "b",
                "value": "si"
            }
                        
        ],
        "status": "approved",
        "create_time": "2023-02-21T23:07:24Z",

    },
    {
            
        "first_name": "Eliza",
        "last_name": "Carbajal Leon",
        "email": "milacanaleslora@gmail.com",
        "custom_questions": [
            {
                "title": "a",
                "value": "no"
            },
            {
                "title": "e",
                "value": "identiti"
            }
                        
        ],
        "status": "approved",
        "create_time": "2023-02-21T23:07:24Z",

    }
]
```

I have applied the following code to normalize the data

```
pp1 = pd.json_normalize(apend)
pp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(np.concatenate(pp1\['custom_questions'\]).tolist())
crear = pd.pivot_table(pp, values='value',columns='title', aggfunc= list).reset_index()
crear = (crear.apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index().drop('index', 1))
ee = crear.drop(\["level_0", "level_1"\], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
unir = pd.merge(pp1,ee, how = "outer", left_index = True, right_index = True)
unir = unir.drop(\['custom_questions'\], axis = 1)
```

i get output like this

[image]

but I lose the information of the third user. Column e is listed as information for the first user. I need that when exploiting or using pivot, the information can be ordered correctly.

the output should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chaining json.normalize() and pivot():

```
meta_columns = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "status", "create_time"]

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=apend,
    meta=meta_columns,
    record_path="custom_questions"
).pivot(
    index=meta_columns,
    columns="title",
    values="value"
).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   first_name        last_name                      email    status           create_time   a    b    c         e
0       Eliza    Carbajal Leon  milacanaleslora@gmail.com  approved  2023-02-21T23:07:24Z  no  NaN  NaN  identiti
1  Milagritos     Canales Lora  milacanaleslora@gmail.com  approved  2023-02-21T23:07:24Z  no   si  NaN       NaN
2  Raúl Pedro  Moreno Zavaleta    raulmoreno147@gmail.com  approved  2023-02-18T17:25:30Z  si   no  001       NaN
```

Comment: I used it but I get this error TypeError: String indices must be integers

Comment: be more specific which line causes that error. This works on your sample data perhaps your real data is causing it